# Windows 10 : How sync volume level control between two devices (communication & default)

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, control-panel

I have one audio device which is the default playback device (speakers) and another which is the communication playback device (headset). Windows audio control panel is like bellow:

[image: Capture showing sound control panel with a headset in communications device and speakers in default device]

Currently, if I use my keys to control the volume (on the keyboard), only the speakers volume is changed. The volume of the headset remain the same.

I'm searching a way to change the sound level of both device only with one key input. I see two case:

1. Absolute sync: headset and speakers volume is equal: (headset 10, speakers 10) > key + > (headset 12, speakers 12)
2. Relative sync: headset and speakers may be presets differently: (headset 10, speakers 20) > key + > (headset 12, speakers 22)

I did some research and did not find anything about this (only per device control or quick troubleshooting tool). To me both case described above are fine, but maybe other readers would need one specific case.

Comment: Faced with exactly the same problem as you. An idea I have is to somehow merge the two audio devices together so that the volume control is identical, then split the output out again. Another idea is to somehow map the volume key to a macro that is able to move the slider for both outputs at the same time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a tool that does exactly that:
https://github.com/Arcitec/VolumeLinker/releases/tag/v1.0.0.1

It uses Microsoft Visual C++ runtime libraries which targets Windows OS and allows to control the volume of any audio output device. It has the ability to link volume from one device to another - which is what you need in case for linking speakers and headphones. If you needed to link more device volumes together, this too will not suffice.

In my case, I use the tool to control the Bluetooth device that is also connected using an analog cable.
This way I can have low latency and volume control.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1199553)